# Go: telegram api, получение сообщений

Tags: golang, telegram-bot

Вроде бы рабочий код получения сообщений для бота в телеграмме по api, но как правильно реализовать получение разных сообщений (текстовые, изображения, файлы), получается для каждого типа сообщений разная структура.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// TextMessage структура JSON полученных текстовых сообщений
type TextMessage struct {
    Ok     bool `json:"ok"`
    Result []struct {
        UpdateID int `json:"update_id"`
        Message  struct {
            MessageID int `json:"message_id"`
            From      struct {
                ID           int    `json:"id"`
                IsBot        bool   `json:"is_bot"`
                FirstName    string `json:"first_name"`
                LastName     string `json:"last_name"`
                LanguageCode string `json:"language_code"`
            } `json:"from"`
            Chat struct {
                ID        int    `json:"id"`
                FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
                LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
                Type      string `json:"type"`
            } `json:"chat"`
            Date int    `json:"date"`
            Text string `json:"text"`
        } `json:"message"`
    } `json:"result"`
}

func main() {

    url := "https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getUpdates"

    getText, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer getText.Body.Close()
    text, err := ioutil.ReadAll(getText.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bodyGet := []byte(text)

    var app = TextMessage{}
    err1 := json.Unmarshal(bodyGet, &app)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatal("error")
    }

    for _, row := range app.Result {
        fmt.Printf("UpdateID:%d  ChatID:%d  Text:%s\n", row.UpdateID, row.Message.Chat.ID, row.Message.Text)
    }

}
```

Структура для файла

```
type FileMessage struct {
    Ok     bool `json:"ok"`
    Result []struct {
        UpdateID int `json:"update_id"`
        Message  struct {
            MessageID int `json:"message_id"`
            From      struct {
                ID           int    `json:"id"`
                IsBot        bool   `json:"is_bot"`
                FirstName    string `json:"first_name"`
                LastName     string `json:"last_name"`
                LanguageCode string `json:"language_code"`
            } `json:"from"`
            Chat struct {
                ID        int    `json:"id"`
                FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
                LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
                Type      string `json:"type"`
            } `json:"chat"`
            Date     int `json:"date"`
            Document struct {
                FileName string `json:"file_name"`
                MimeType string `json:"mime_type"`
                Thumb    struct {
                    FileID   string `json:"file_id"`
                    FileSize int    `json:"file_size"`
                    Width    int    `json:"width"`
                    Height   int    `json:"height"`
                } `json:"thumb"`
                FileID   string `json:"file_id"`
                FileSize int    `json:"file_size"`
            } `json:"document"`
        } `json:"message"`
    } `json:"result"`
}
```

Структура для изображения

```
type ImgMessage struct {
    Ok     bool `json:"ok"`
    Result []struct {
        UpdateID int `json:"update_id"`
        Message  struct {
            MessageID int `json:"message_id"`
            From      struct {
                ID           int    `json:"id"`
                IsBot        bool   `json:"is_bot"`
                FirstName    string `json:"first_name"`
                LastName     string `json:"last_name"`
                LanguageCode string `json:"language_code"`
            } `json:"from"`
            Chat struct {
                ID        int    `json:"id"`
                FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
                LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
                Type      string `json:"type"`
            } `json:"chat"`
            Date  int `json:"date"`
            Photo []struct {
                FileID   string `json:"file_id"`
                FileSize int    `json:"file_size"`
                Width    int    `json:"width"`
                Height   int    `json:"height"`
            } `json:"photo"`
        } `json:"message"`
    } `json:"result"`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализуйте максимальную структуру и заполняйте нужные поля. Посмотрите, как сделано в https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api (и даже могу посоветовать использовать этот api, он хороший, если нет непременной задачи реализовать собственный ;-)

Comment: С моими знаниями ГО вряд ли, получиться реализовать хорошего бота, задача просто поучиться ) , спасибо за ответ, буду разбираться на примерах толковых парней.